# How to display messages to the user when they click the submit button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to get data from a table.

I don't know if my code can get a value from my table.

```
<script> 
  function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["assessmentForm"]["perf_rating11"].value;
    var y = document.forms["assessmentForm"]["skaneed_N11"].value;
    var txt;
    if (confirm((x==5||4)&&(y==1))== true){
      document.write("text here");
    } else {
      // empty else statement.
    }
  }
</script>
```

This is my submit code:

```
     <form name="assessmentForm" action="http://localhost/login/insert.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="get">
```

The data is from a table like this:

```
    <td><?php include 'connection_ska_c11.php';?></td>
    <td style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;"><input type="radio" name="perf_rating11"
    <?php if (isset($perf_rating11) && $perf_rating11=="outstanding")   echo "checked";?>
    value="5" required></td>
    <td style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;"><input type="radio"  name="perf_rating11"
    <?php if (isset($perf_rating11) &&  $perf_rating11=="very_satisfactory") echo "checked";?>
    value="4" required></td>
    <td style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;"><input type="radio" name="perf_rating11"
    <?php if (isset($perf_rating11) && $perf_rating11=="satisfactory") echo "checked";?>
    value="3"></td>
    <td style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;"><input type="radio" name="perf_rating11"
    <?php if (isset($perf_rating11) && $perf_rating11=="unsatisfactory") echo "checked";?>
    value="2"></td>
    <td style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;"><input type="radio" name="perf_rating11"
    <?php if (isset($perf_rating11) && $perf_rating11=="poor") echo "checked";?>
    value="1"></td>
```

Comment: Have you tried console logging the values to see if they're there?

Comment: check it on console what's the values going when you submit on form.

Comment: "i dont know if these codes can get value from my table". What happens when you try?

Comment: From a quick observation, `if (confirm((x==5||4)&&(y==1))== true){` does not make a lot of sense. Are you trying to test the values of x and y? `confirm` displays a dialog box to the user - not much use for testing values. I suggest you read the plentiful online documentation for the functions you're trying to use, and also learn how to use your browser's developer tools to check for syntax and runtime errors.

Comment: It is difficult to tell what you are wanting. But there is an error with confirm((x==5||4)&&(y==1). You need to change it to confirm((x==5||x==4)&&(y==1)

Comment: @jeff the correction to the logic make sense, but using `confirm` will just result (assuming it runs at all) in a dialog box which says "true" or "false", with ok and cancel buttons. It won't test the variables themselves.

Comment: It display dialog box with false title and if i click ok it goes back in the page and when i click cancel it save the data to database. meaning it doesnt have function?

Comment: @jeff Yes I want to test the data of x and y, will try your suggestion

Comment: @ADyson when I click ok in the diaog box I get redirected to a page with my text in document.write and when i click cancel data saves into my database

Comment: you need to `return true;` or `return false;` from the validateForm function depending whether you want it to continue submitting the form, or cancel it, respectively. Otherwise it will assume you want to continue submitting it, which is the default behaviour. But why do you want a dialog box? What should the user decide? Surely you want the computer to check the values of x and y for itself?

Comment: As I explained to you and Jeff, using `confirm` makes no sense. It does not cause the `if` to evaluate X and Y, it causes the result of that evaluation to display to the user (hence "false" showing in the dialog), and then the result of the dialog (true if OK is pressed, false otherwise) is the value that is evaluated by the `if` statement. So the user is deciding the validity of the form, not your logic.

Comment: @ADyson I want the user to know that there inputs are conflicting but the user can decide if that's okay or they want to go back and change their inputs

Comment: @ADyson so what code or function should I use if confirm is not right?

Comment: `if` is quite sufficient. `if ((x == 5 || x == 4) && (y==1) == true) {` will evaluate your actual x and y variables against the constants you've supplied in there. Once you've decided that, _then_ you can alert the user to any problems. Currently you're trying to talk to the user before you've actually tested the values.

Comment: I follow your suggestion but there is no suggestion box appearing even my values are true to my condition

Comment: yes, well you need to provide one somewhere else, obviously. They don't just magically appear on their own. What I wrote was just a hint, not the full solution. Another hint: write something like `if (confirm("Your input values conflict, do you want to continue?") == true) { //...replace this comment with whatever you need to` in the appropriate place in your code (I don't know whether this is when the first `if` is true or false, it's not clear from your description).

Comment: @ADyson I test my condition in if, I put x==5 in my  if condition then its worjing fine, but whenever i put this if ((x == 5 || x == 4) && (y==1) == true), it goes on like there is no condtion. it seems to me that my condtion cant be read.

Comment: try simply `if ((x == 5 || x == 4) && y==1)` instead

Comment: @ADyson its okay now, thanks see my answer in this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using this

`var y = document.forms["assessmentForm"]["skaneed_N11"].value;`

I use jquery

```
 var y = $('.skaneed_N11:checked').val();
```

So now my code is

```
 <script> 
 function validateForm(form){
  var x = document.forms["assessmentForm"]["perf_rating11"].value;

  var y = $('.skaneed_N11:checked').val();
  if ((x == 5 || x == 4) && (y == 1)){
    confirm("Your input values conflict, do you want to continue?");
    return false;
  }

  }


 </script>
```

Comment: Yeah that's the jQuery syntax for finding an element. You'd be better to paste the whole code snippet now for future readers, since that clearly isn't the only bit that needed to be changed from the original to make it work.